# Adding Blocks to R data

Tags: r, vector, split

I have the following data

```
set.seed(1234)
round<-rep(1:12,2)
players<-rep(1:2, c(12,12))
decs<-sample(1:3,24,replace=TRUE)
game<-rep(rep(1:2,c(6,6)),2)
gamematrix<-cbind(players,game,round,decs)
gamematrix

        players game round decs
 [1,]       1    1     1    1
 [2,]       1    1     2    2
 [3,]       1    1     3    2
 [4,]       1    1     4    2
 [5,]       1    1     5    3
 [6,]       1    1     6    2
 [7,]       1    2     7    1
 [8,]       1    2     8    1
 [9,]       1    2     9    2
[10,]       1    2    10    2
[11,]       1    2    11    3
[12,]       1    2    12    2
...
```

Now, I would like to add a column: "block", such that for **each player in each game** the first 3 rounds will be block 1 and the next 3 round will be block 2.

The result for the data above should be:

```
       players game round decs block
 [1,]       1    1     1    1    1
 [2,]       1    1     2    2    1
 [3,]       1    1     3    2    1
 [4,]       1    1     4    2    2
 [5,]       1    1     5    3    2
 [6,]       1    1     6    2    2    
 ...
```

Any ideas how to do it? 
  Thanks!

Comment: And what are the rest? You have more than six of each `players`.

Comment: Тhanks @RichardScriven! I put only partial data for the purpose of simplicity.  The real data has 100 participants with 400 rounds and 4 games.  I want for ** each within each game** divide game into 5 equal blocks (of 20 rounds each).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `ave`

```
cbind(gamematrix, block =ave((gamematrix[,3]-1)%%3==0, 
                      gamematrix[,1], gamematrix[,2], FUN= cumsum))
#      players game round decs block
# [1,]       1    1     1    1     1
# [2,]       1    1     2    2     1
# [3,]       1    1     3    2     1
# [4,]       1    1     4    2     2
# [5,]       1    1     5    3     2
# [6,]       1    1     6    2     2
# [7,]       1    2     7    1     1
# [8,]       1    2     8    1     1
# [9,]       1    2     9    2     1
#[10,]       1    2    10    2     2
#[11,]       1    2    11    3     2
#[12,]       1    2    12    2     2
#[13,]       2    1     1    1     1
#[14,]       2    1     2    3     1
#[15,]       2    1     3    1     1
#[16,]       2    1     4    3     2
#[17,]       2    1     5    1     2
#[18,]       2    1     6    1     2
#[19,]       2    2     7    1     1
#[20,]       2    2     8    1     1
#[21,]       2    2     9    1     1
#[22,]       2    2    10    1     2
#[23,]       2    2    11    1     2
#[24,]       2    2    12    1     2
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun! Can you please explain how the ave function is working here? I realize that "gamematrix[,3]-1)%%3==0" returns the TRUE/FALSE, so it basically split the data. Now it is splited upon players and games? But what does the "cumsum" summarize upon?

Comment: The answer above answers a more general question: If for example you have N participants with 600 rounds, you still can use the code above, to add blocks. Just change the "%%3" to the number of groups you want to build.

Comment: @YefR You are right, Change the number and you will get the number of groups

Comment: @YefR The `cumsum` get the cumulative sum of the logical index for each `players` and `game` (these are grouping variables in the `ave`

Comment: Sorry, but I miss something: if the `cumsum` gives the cumulative sum of logical index for each `players` and `game`, how come that the `block` value for `round` 24 is 2 (shouldn't it be 2+2=4?).

Comment: @YefR I guess you are misunderstanding it.  If you look at the logical index i.e. `(gamematrix[,3]-1)%%3==0#
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[23] FALSE FALSE`  from 19th observation, ie. the TRUE value, it is taking the cumulative sum based on the same values in players and game ('2'), i.e. 19 to 21 wlll be 1 1 1 because `TRUE/FALSE` gets coerced to `1/0` so the cumulative sum will be `1 1 1` until the next TRUE i.e .22nd observation, where it is add 1 to give `2 2 2`